# Conditional trigger in Oracle Forms

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

In database table in status column already status is stored like `O(OPEN)` OR `C(CLOSE)`.

I have to display this status as `OPEN` and `CLOSE` in front end status column in oracle forms developer.

1. Which trigger do I have to use?
2. What is the condition for expected query for that trigger?

Comment: In the table, values are stored as O and C?

Comment: Yes like That only...!

Comment: Is your block is based on a table or a view? If it is based on a view, then you can include the case condition to check O and C.

Comment: Its table actually

Comment: In that case, you can use the approach provided by Elie

Answer (score 2):

You could use the NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE on the data block level, or NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE on the item level, either way you can just use the following, assuming your block name is A and field name is STATUS:

```
if nvl(:a.status,'C') = 'O' then
  :a.status := 'Open';
else
  :a.status := 'Closed';
end if;
```

Comment: I am getting only O and C from status column in Query mode, i need to display 'open' and 'close'.
there is no new mode in that form. only modify and query modes are there

Comment: These two triggers are executed each time the block is loaded or created, they do not rely on the mode you are in. you can also use POST-QUERY to do this.

Comment: These are not the appropriate triggers for this purpose. These are navigation events.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I didn't mean to hurt your feelings, sorry. they just work if you have a better answer please post it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list item for this:

Put the `Item type` to `List Item`
Set the `List Style` to `Poplist`
And in the property Elements in List you can map your values:

> Open to O
>
> Closed to C

Then you will have a drop down list with values Open and Closed and automatically it will use the values attached to it in the database.

Comment: how to disable modification for status column in modify mode..?

Comment: Just put the property insert allowed and update allowed in the database property to No or another option is to put the property enabled to No

Answer (score 0):

I would add a block level post-query trigger and populate a non-base table column. To hold the open/closed status.